'fr<Tab>' doesn't expand at all
I'm trying to take lecture notes using org-mode and cdlatex-mode. The problem I meet is when I try to use Tab to expand fr it doesn't expand correctly.
\(fr<Tab>\) will become \(\begin{frame}[]\frametitle{}\end{frame}\) instead of \(\frac{}{}\) and there is a warning saying that Warning (org-element): ‘org-element-at-point’ cannot be used in non-Org buffer #<buffer MatrixComputation.org> (latex-mode).
I'm using doom emacs and only open org-cdlatex-mode as a minor mode. How can I fix this problem to make \(fr<Tab>\) works properly?

One question per question please.

https://docs.doomemacs.org/latest/modules/lang/latex/, paragraph 4.3, which provides a solution but this not works for me. https://orgmode.org/manual/Conflicts.html#Conflicts also gives a solution but it doesn't work for me either, I just add those codes at the bottom of config.el. However, it is the conflict between org-mode and yasnippet(yas-minor-mode), I turned it off just now and it works well.
